# Print data in array in a specific mannar java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of array element an i need to print the elemt on a specific way

For example my array element is [1,2,3,4,5,6] and what i need to make this array as [1,6,2,5,3,4] am a student and beginner  in the programming world,the sorting is of some kind alternative way, How can i achive this in java

Thank you

Comment: Store the 1st element (0-based index) into a variable, then overwrite the 1st element with the 5th element, then overwrite the 5th element with the content of your variable. Looks like you have much to learn, and stackoverflow isn't the best resource at this level.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: what have you tried so far? it's not clear if you just want to print it in that order or re arrange the elements in the array, or even create a new array and arrange the items in it, however i can give you a hint, try it, and post some code here, then we can help you, the hint is, to use 2 pointers (index) ex, `int head=0` `int tail = array.length-1` you can make a `while (head < tail){}` or other condition. you can use [head] and [tail] to get and set elements, each iteration you will need to `++head` , `--tail`, and you need to handle special cases, ex, array length is ODD or EVEN ...

Comment: Please check this guideline: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @SamwinishereHere I doubt that would be helping you, and that certainly wouldn't be helping the community (I shouldn't encourage people asking for ready-to-use code here, that's not the point of the site). Tell me what in my comment you don't know how to implement and I'll point you to a resource that should help.

Comment: Thank u @yazan ur help helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this a perfect way but you can achieve the required result if you follow the snippet, here i made a startindex and endindex variable and add based on the even or odd size of arraylist, you can understand when you go through the snippet

```
    Integer[]myCurrentData={1,2,3,4,5,6}; 

    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = myCurrentData.length;

    ArrayList<Integer> rearrangedData = new ArrayList<>();

    //Let add a for loop for this example >You can change asper your requirement
       for(int i=0;i<myCurrentData.length;i++)
          {     
            if (rearrangedData.size() % 2 == 0) //if even number add start index
               {

                   rearrangedData.add(myCurrentData[startIndex]);

                     startIndex++;

                } else {
                        endIndex--; 

                       rearrangedData.add(myCurrentData[endIndex]);


                }
           }
 //Just to print the data
    String printString="[";
    for(int i=0;i<rearrangedData.size();i++)
    {
        printString=printString+rearrangedData.get(i)+",";
    }
    printString=printString+"]";
    System.out.println("Rearranged Data"+printString);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, please notice `input` and `mannar` have same size.

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("This", "is", "a", "sample", "array"));
ArrayList<Integer> mannarArray = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5, 3, 4));
for (int index = 0; index < mannarArray.size(); index ++) {
    System.out.println(input.get(mannarArray.get(index) - 1));
}
```